# conditionlal grouping column and returning y first and second majority values as new columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, mode

I have one complex problem I am trying to solve.
I have a sample of dataframe below. I want to split based on Name column at every (5th row/50ft interval). For each split, I want to return first majority occuring value based on column D and 2nd majority occuring value of this same column as new columns each (First and Second Majority). Also, at the point where the group by name doesnt have up to 5rows or 50ft interval, it should still group it and return the first majority and second majority value. if at any splitting, the first majority and second majority are equal, it should return the first number it encounter as first majority and the other as second majority.

```
| Name| A |  B  | C |D |first Majority|second Majority|
| ----|---|-----| --|--|--------------|---------------|
| cat | 0 |10   | 1 |23|22            |23             |
| cat | 10|20   | 2 |22|              |               |
| cat | 20|30   | 3 |23|              |               |
| cat | 30|40   | 5 |22|              |               |
| cat | 40|50   | 8 |22|              |               |
| cat | 50|60   | 9 |27|27            |24             |
| cat | 60|70   | 59|24|              |               |
| cat | 70|80   | 11|24|              |               |
| cat | 80|90   | 60|27|              |               |
| dog | 0 |10   | 56|23|23            |22             |
| dog | 10|20   | 69|23|              |               |
| dog | 20|30   | 89|22|              |               |
| dog | 30|40   | 50|23|              |               |
| dog | 40|50   | 52|22|              |               |
| dog | 50|60   | 66|27|27            |24             |
| dog | 60|70   | 67|24|              |               |
| dog | 70|80   | 47|27|              |               |
| dog | 80|90   | 48|24|              |               |
| dog | 90|100  | 89 |27|              |               |
```

Comment: What is your expected ouput?

Comment: The last two columns